# R parallel processing parLapply not recognizing data

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to run the following code in parallel. What's happening is there is some predictor data loaded, then the function `predRegion` subsets the data for the appropriate region, loads the correct prediction model object, and scores the data. This works fine if I use `lapply` without parallel processing. But when I try to use the parallel package's `parLapply` I get an error saying `3 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'df' not found`. Am I doing something wrong?

```
df <- read.csv('fctInputs.csv')
predRegion <- function(r){
  #Subset data for region
  df <- data[grep(r, names(df))]

  #Read in and score regional model
  model <- readRDS(paste0(r, 'model.rds'))
  df$forecast <- predict(model, df)

  return(df)
}

##This code works  
lapply(c('AU','TX','LA','MA','NE'), predRegion)

##This results in error saying "3 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'df' not found"
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
parLapply(cl=cl, c('AU','TX','LA','MA','NE'), predRegion)
```

Comment: I'm now seeing here (http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2016/01/parallel-computing-in-r/) that all the necessary data and functions must be loaded in the parallel processing :(

Comment: You can use `cluseterEvalQ` to load libraries and `clusterExport` to load data to your clusters.

Comment: The solution of @lm works: The clusters do not share the objects of the global environment by default. This is done with clusterExport(cl,"df"), which is going to load df to all the clusters.